# Angular-cli project, hosted inde a Visual Studio Core 2.2 Web Api project, fails to compile, randomly

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I have a Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 2.2 project based on the API template.
Inside the Api project I have created a new angular-cli based web application.

Visual Studio Build fails to compile randomly. Build fails. Then I compile again without changing anything and the build completes successfully. If I build again, it will now compile consistently but with warningss, and suddenly it will start fail again with same errors and repeat.

When it fails I get 24 build errors similar to this. It package folder under nodes_modules.

```
TS2420  Build:Class 'MockMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'. C:\somePath\node_modules\@angular\flex-layout\core\typings\match-media\mock\mock-match-media.d.ts
```

When it compiles I have 8 warnings like this:

```
C:\somePath\node_modules\@angular\flex-layout\core\typings\match-media\mock\mock-match-media.d.ts(62,22): error TS2420: Build:Class 'MockMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.
```

I am not aware of anything that is doing any operations on the files under node_modules at compile time. The angular-cli app should be completely ignored by MsBuild, but it is clearly not.

Under "project properties" --> "Typescript build" I have selected "Use latest available" and removed the checkmark in the "Enable" checkbox.

This is my project.csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
  <ServerGarbageCollection>True</ServerGarbageCollection>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>False</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
  <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Kestrel" Version="3.3.617" />
 </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES2015</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>ES6</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>True</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like this issue https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/851

Comment: Yes. it is the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by upgrading to the latest version

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@latest
```